# background-image in PHP file not showing up

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a php file that includes html code and displays user's account. I would like to add an image for background and repeat it. However, I have tried almost everything and can't display it! The image exist inside a folder named "style" and this folder exist where the rest php files are.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>

<head>
<title>My Account</title>
<style>
    body{
        background-image: url("/style/ebook_back.png");

    }
    h2{
        background-color: red;
      }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    //Some PHP code...
?>

<h1>My Account</h1> <hr>
<h2>Account Details</h2>
<h3>Check & Modify personal details</h3>

<hr>
<h2>My Orders</h2>
<h3>Check & Modify my orders</h3>

<hr>
<h2>My Wishlist</h2>
<h3>Check & Update my wishlist</h3>

<?php More PHP code...?>
</body>

</html>
```

The background colour for the h2 is displayed correctly but the image does not showed up! Dimensions are 200 x 200px

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the page in a browser like Firefox. Take a look at the debug console like Firebug and list which resources the page wanted to load. Most likely your background image is not located at `yourdomain.example/style/ebook_back.png`

Comment: You are right! Says not found. But when I am trying to open the image with browser, directory is the same...

Comment: where is your `style` directory in relation to this php file?

Comment: style directory exist under the same folder as account.php

Comment: That's make no sense! I've saved the the image with different extension (jpg) and now is working! Is there any known problem with png images?

Comment: None that I know of. A wild guess: Case sensitive filenames? You should probably have a look at the webservers' logfiles to see what file he is looking for that isn't found.

Comment: Finally! I've discovered what was going wrong. Photoshop saves the image in a PNG format that HTML can't recognise. So, I've just open and re-save PNG image with another image editor and now is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving wrong path. Add dot at the beginning or remove first slash.

```
background-image: url("./style/ebook_back.png");
```

or

```
background-image: url("style/ebook_back.png");
```

Comment: it's impossible. Are you sure about the file and folder name?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure about the path?
maybe you should try this "./style/ebook_back.png" for a realtive path with a dot

Answer (score 0):

Do you have firebug installed on your browser.  It could be related with your directory structure . If you have firebug installed check if you have an error

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Try removing the / from the path.

Comment: I am getting the error status 404. However image its there. How can retrieve correct directory?